# Is it true that $Dim(Col(A))=Dim(Range(A^T))$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that $rankA = rankA^T$ and after examining the textbook, I believe that this has something to do with $Col$ and $Range$ of $A$.

However, I am unsure if this statement is even true at all. My assumption is that $Dim(Col(A))$ does not necessary be the same as $Dim(Col(A^T))$. So how do we know that $Dim(Col(A))$ will be equal to  $Dim(Range(A^T))$. I am looking at the elementary matricies of $A$ and $A^T$ but so far had not made any progress.

Thank you for the helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to see that is the following : 
$A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is of rank $r$ iif $\exists P,Q\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that : 
$$A=PJ_r Q$$
where $J_r$ is the diagonal matrix with $r$ ones on the diagonal (r first).

Then 
$$A^T=Q^T J_r P^T$$
And you can see the result.

Edit : if the matrices are not square you can also think about the same result

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am still a beginner in diagonalizing so I am learning more from here too:  http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-701-algebra-i-fall-2010/study-materials/MIT18_701F10_rrk_crk.pdf. Your suggestions really helped me. :)

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the range and the column space are the same thing.

Say $A$ has $n$ pivot rows, then the columns of $A$ span some $n$-dimensional subspace, so $\dim col(A)=n$. 
But if $A$ has $n$ pivot rows, then it also has $n$ pivot columns (try a few examples), i.e. $\dim row(A)=n$.

This can commonly be heard as 'the column rank and the row rank of a matrix are equal'. This implies that $\dim col(A)=\dim row(A)$.

Transposing the matrix $A$ means the column space of $A$ becomes the row space of $A^T$, and the row space of $A$ becomes the column space of $A^T$.

Therefore $\dim col(A)=\dim row(A^T)=\dim col(A^T)$.

Comment: Thank you, especially the concept of "Row Rank = Column Rank". It helps me a lot in researching more on this topic. :)